# Install Facebook Messenger on iPhone 3Gs running iOS 6.1.6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I reset my iPhone 3Gs but am unable to install Facebook Messenger back on my iPhone as it requires iOS 7. How can I install Facebook Messenger on my iPhone 3Gs running iOS 6.1.6?

Answer (score 5):

It will let you download the last compatible version if you already have the app in your purchase history. You can add the app to your purchase history using iTunes on your computer, since iTunes is version-agnostic.

Once you've downloaded the app on iTunes, it will be in your purchase history and attempting to download it again on your device should prompt you to accept an older version of the app.

Comment: This worked for my son's iphone 3 that he inherited; it's his first iphone so had never downloaded Facebook before but we were able to do so when it was plugged into the PC via the iTunes Store.