# Can't download facebook in my new iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone

I bought a new IPhone 3GS and can't download Messenger, Facebook, hike etc.
Why?

How to download?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the last compatible version of an app if you already have the app in your purchase history. You can add the app to your purchase history using iTunes on your computer, since iTunes is version-agnostic.

Once you've downloaded the app on iTunes, it will be in your purchase history and attempting to download it again on your device should prompt you to accept an older version of the app.

Comment: Ahh… I wasn't sure this would apply to messenger, as it wasn't split to separate apps until iOS 7, but I since found this dupe confirming it can be done - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153195/install-facebook-messenger-on-iphone-3gs-running-ios-6-1-6

Comment: @Tetsujin Aha, I knew I'd written this for SE! I found a snippet in my notes app but couldn't find where I'd used it before, thanks.

Comment: Most welcome. It was your answer here that actually prompted me to search further.

Answer (score 1):

*See grgarside's answer for a workaround if you have a computer running iTunes*

You can't, I'm afraid.

[Facebook Messenger](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/messenger/id454638411?mt=8) requires iOS 7 minimum spec, yet the [iPhone 3GS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Obsolete_or_discontinued_models) is only capable of using up to iOS 6.1.6
You would need an iPhone 4 or newer.